# Why is that if $z^n = |z|^2$, then $|z| = 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

We have $z^{n-1} = \bar{z}\ \forall\ n > 2$ which gives us $z^n = |z|^2$, but I dont see why that means $|z| = 1$?

Comment: Take the absolute value of both sides.

Comment: Well, $z=0$ also satisfies that…

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD $|z|^n = |z|^2$ so $|z|^{n-2} = 1$ or $|z| = 1$?

Comment: Yes, that seems right (since $|z|$ is a positive real number and there is only one positive real root of unity) — though note that you can only divide by $|z|$ if $z\ne0$, which explains the other solution.